# NVIDIA driver unloads after a system suspend

Tags: debian, nvidia

I am having a recurring issue with NVIDIA's driver not working after my system resumes from a suspend. I current am using Nsight for Eclipse to learn how to write CUDA apps.

The problem is that whenever I suspend my system, Nsight doesn't detect my GPU when I resume.

This problem is pretty much exactly what I experienced and describe in an [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339362/cuda-context-for-nvenc-not-found-after-system-suspend). The same system, the same fix does the trick (close, reload `nvidia_uvm`, open and it works again).

**System info**

- 375.26 proprietary driver
- GPU: MSI GTX 970
- uname -a: Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64, #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30)
- OS: Debian 8.7 Jessie

I use XFCE 4.10 if that makes a difference to how the action buttons work.

I will be happy to post/update with any debug information needed.

Comment: Bump? Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I frequently lose my Gnome session on resume from suspend.  Have to log in again.  Same issue maybe?  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=891960